# cmake cannot find (=link) boost libraries when using MAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I am trying to cross compile my C++ application which uses boost. Therefore I compiled boost by myself. For CMake I created a "toolchain file" which I specify to CMake like this:

```
cmake . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-g++.cmake
```

The file **arm-linux-gnueabi-g++.cmake** contains among others the paths to my compiled boost version:

```
# Boost ARM
SET(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /home/ubuntu/development/boost_1_55_0)
SET(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /home/ubuntu/development/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib)
```

My **CMakeLists.txt** contains this:

```
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS chrono date_time filesystem locale log regex system thread REQUIRED)
...
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${ApplicationName} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

As a result CMake tells me:

> ```
> Boost version: 1.55.0
> Found the following Boost libraries:
>     chrono
>     date_time
>     ...
>     thread
> ```

So compiling works fine but when it comes to linking I get the following linker errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_chrono
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -ldate_time
...
```

I dont get this, *BOOST_LIBRARYDIR* definitely contains the libboost_chrono.a (and in general all static libs). The following command within my CMakeLists.txt even shows that the *.a-files are found.

```
message(STATUS ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why, but the following:

```
SET(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR /home/ubuntu/development/boost_1_55_0)
SET(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR /home/ubuntu/development/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib)
```

needs to be changed/reduced to

```
SET(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR /home/ubuntu/development/boost_1_55_0)
```

It is not necessary to specify BOOST_ROOT or BOOST_LIBRARYDIR. Furthermore BOOST_INCLUDEDIR has been changed to Boost_INCLUDE_DIR. If this variable is set CMake magically finds all libraries by itself when using FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ...)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but something else that should have been a comment to that question.